# occurred starting process 'command 'C:\*********\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd'' in android studio

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am using yt-watchme-master for live streaming videos from our mobile to Youtube.

I used one third party library :- https://github.com/youtube/yt-watchme

Here, they are using c++ code that's why I installed NDK in my android studio but still errors are coming up.

Can some one help me please?

Below is the entire code given.

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>

#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavutil/opt.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

JNIEXPORT jboolean
        JNICALL Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                                 jint width, jint height,
                                                                 jint audio_sample_rate,
                                                                 jstring rtmp_url);
        JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_shutdown(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz
);
JNIEXPORT jintJNICALL
Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz,
        jbyteArray
yuv_image);
JNIEXPORT jint
        JNICALL Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame(JNIEnv *env,
                                                                             jobject thiz,
                                                                             jshortArray audio_data,
                                                                             jint length);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#define LOGI(...) __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "ffmpeg-jni", __VA_ARGS__)
#define URL_WRONLY 2
        static AVFormatContext *fmt_context;
        static AVStream *video_stream;
        static AVStream *audio_stream;

        static int pts
= 0;
static int last_audio_pts = 0;

// Buffers for UV format conversion
static unsigned char *u_buf;
static unsigned char *v_buf;

static int enable_audio = 1;
static int64_t audio_samples_written = 0;
static int audio_sample_rate = 0;

// Stupid buffer for audio samples. Not even a proper ring buffer
#define AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE 16384  // 2x what we get from Java
static short audio_buf[AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE];
static int audio_buf_size = 0;

void AudioBuffer_Push(const short *audio, int num_samples) {
    if (audio_buf_size >= AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE - num_samples) {
        LOGI("AUDIO BUFFER OVERFLOW: %i + %i > %i", audio_buf_size, num_samples,
             AUDIO_MAX_BUF_SIZE);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num_samples; i++) {
        audio_buf[audio_buf_size++] = audio[i];
    }
}

int AudioBuffer_Size() { return audio_buf_size; }

short *AudioBuffer_Get() { return audio_buf; }

void AudioBuffer_Pop(int num_samples) {
    if (num_samples > audio_buf_size) {
        LOGI("Audio buffer Pop WTF: %i vs %i", num_samples, audio_buf_size);
        return;
    }
    memmove(audio_buf, audio_buf + num_samples, num_samples * sizeof(short));
    audio_buf_size -= num_samples;
}

void AudioBuffer_Clear() {
    memset(audio_buf, 0, sizeof(audio_buf));
    audio_buf_size = 0;
}

static void log_callback(void *ptr, int level, const char *fmt, va_list vl) {
    char x[2048];
    vsnprintf(x, 2048, fmt, vl);
    LOGI(x);
}

JNIEXPORT jboolean
        JNICALL Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_init(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,
                                                                 jint width, jint height,
                                                                 jint audio_sample_rate_param,
                                                                 jstring rtmp_url) {
    avcodec_register_all();
    av_register_all();
    av_log_set_callback(log_callback);

    fmt_context = avformat_alloc_context();
    AVOutputFormat *ofmt = av_guess_format("flv", NULL, NULL);
    if (ofmt) {
        LOGI("av_guess_format returned %s", ofmt->long_name);
    } else {
        LOGI("av_guess_format fail");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    fmt_context->oformat = ofmt;
    LOGI("creating video stream");
    video_stream = av_new_stream(fmt_context, 0);

    if (enable_audio) {
        LOGI("creating audio stream");
        audio_stream = av_new_stream(fmt_context, 1);
    }

    // Open Video Codec.
    // ======================
    AVCodec *video_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_H264);
    if (!video_codec) {
        LOGI("Did not find the video codec");
        return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
    } else {
        LOGI("Video codec found!");
    }
    AVCodecContext *video_codec_ctx = video_stream->codec;
    video_codec_ctx->codec_id = video_codec->id;
    video_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
    video_codec_ctx->level = 31;

    video_codec_ctx->width = width;
    video_codec_ctx->height = height;
    video_codec_ctx->pix_fmt = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
    video_codec_ctx->rc_max_rate = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->rc_buffer_size = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->gop_size = 12;
    video_codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->slices = 8;
    video_codec_ctx->b_frame_strategy = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->coder_type = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->me_cmp = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->me_range = 16;
    video_codec_ctx->qmin = 10;
    video_codec_ctx->qmax = 51;
    video_codec_ctx->keyint_min = 25;
    video_codec_ctx->refs = 3;
    video_codec_ctx->trellis = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->scenechange_threshold = 40;
    video_codec_ctx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_LOOP_FILTER;
    video_codec_ctx->me_method = ME_HEX;
    video_codec_ctx->me_subpel_quality = 6;
    video_codec_ctx->i_quant_factor = 0.71;
    video_codec_ctx->qcompress = 0.6;
    video_codec_ctx->max_qdiff = 4;
    video_codec_ctx->time_base.den = 10;
    video_codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
    video_codec_ctx->bit_rate = 3200 * 1000;
    video_codec_ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = 0;
    video_codec_ctx->flags2 |= 0x00000100;

    fmt_context->bit_rate = 4000 * 1000;

    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx, "partitions", "i8x8,i4x4,p8x8,b8x8", 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "direct-pred", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "rc-lookahead", 0, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "fast-pskip", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "mixed-refs", 1, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "8x8dct", 0, 0);
    av_opt_set_int(video_codec_ctx, "weightb", 0, 0);

    if (fmt_context->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
        video_codec_ctx->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    LOGI("Opening video codec");
    AVDictionary *vopts = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "profile", "main", 0);
    //av_dict_set(&vopts, "vprofile", "main", 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "rc-lookahead", 0, 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "tune", "film", 0);
    av_dict_set(&vopts, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "film", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
    av_opt_set(video_codec_ctx->priv_data, "tune", "film", 0);
    int open_res = avcodec_open2(video_codec_ctx, video_codec, &vopts);
    if (open_res < 0) {
        LOGI("Error opening video codec: %i", open_res);
        return JNI_FALSE;   // leak!
    }

    // Open Audio Codec.
    // ======================

    if (enable_audio) {
        AudioBuffer_Clear();
        audio_sample_rate = audio_sample_rate_param;
        AVCodec *audio_codec = avcodec_find_encoder(AV_CODEC_ID_AAC);
        if (!audio_codec) {
            LOGI("Did not find the audio codec");
            return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
        } else {
            LOGI("Audio codec found!");
        }
        AVCodecContext *audio_codec_ctx = audio_stream->codec;
        audio_codec_ctx->codec_id = audio_codec->id;
        audio_codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
        audio_codec_ctx->bit_rate = 128000;
        audio_codec_ctx->bit_rate_tolerance = 16000;
        audio_codec_ctx->channels = 1;
        audio_codec_ctx->profile = FF_PROFILE_AAC_LOW;
        audio_codec_ctx->sample_fmt = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT;
        audio_codec_ctx->sample_rate = 44100;

        LOGI("Opening audio codec");
        AVDictionary *opts = NULL;
        av_dict_set(&opts, "strict", "experimental", 0);
        open_res = avcodec_open2(audio_codec_ctx, audio_codec, &opts);
        LOGI("audio frame size: %i", audio_codec_ctx->frame_size);

        if (open_res < 0) {
            LOGI("Error opening audio codec: %i", open_res);
            return JNI_FALSE;   // leak!
        }
    }

    const jbyte *url = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, NULL);

    // Point to an output file
    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        if (avio_open(&fmt_context->pb, url, URL_WRONLY) < 0) {
            LOGI("ERROR: Could not open file %s", url);
            return JNI_FALSE;  // leak!
        }
    }
    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, rtmp_url, url);

    LOGI("Writing output header.");
    // Write file header
    if (avformat_write_header(fmt_context, NULL) != 0) {
        LOGI("ERROR: av_write_header failed");
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    pts = 0;
    last_audio_pts = 0;
    audio_samples_written = 0;

    // Initialize buffers for UV format conversion
    int frame_size = video_codec_ctx->width * video_codec_ctx->height;
    u_buf = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(frame_size / 4);
    v_buf = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(frame_size / 4);

    LOGI("ffmpeg encoding init done");
    return JNI_TRUE;
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_shutdown(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz
) {
av_write_trailer(fmt_context);
avio_close(fmt_context
->pb);
avcodec_close(video_stream
->codec);
if (enable_audio) {
avcodec_close(audio_stream
->codec);
}
av_free(fmt_context);
av_free(u_buf);
av_free(v_buf);

fmt_context = NULL;
u_buf = NULL;
v_buf = NULL;
}

JNIEXPORT jintJNICALL
Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_encodeVideoFrame(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz,
        jbyteArray
yuv_image) {
int yuv_length = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env, yuv_image);
unsigned char *yuv_data = (*env)->GetByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, 0);

AVCodecContext *video_codec_ctx = video_stream->codec;
//LOGI("Yuv size: %i w: %i h: %i", yuv_length, video_codec_ctx->width, video_codec_ctx->height);

int frame_size = video_codec_ctx->width * video_codec_ctx->height;

const unsigned char *uv = yuv_data + frame_size;

// Convert YUV from NV12 to I420. Y channel is the same so we don't touch it,
// we just have to deinterleave UV.
for (
int i = 0;
i < frame_size / 4; i++) {
v_buf[i] = uv[i * 2];
u_buf[i] = uv[i * 2 + 1];
}

AVFrame source;
memset(&source, 0, sizeof(AVFrame));
source.data[0] =
yuv_data;
source.data[1] =
u_buf;
source.data[2] =
v_buf;
source.linesize[0] = video_codec_ctx->
width;
source.linesize[1] = video_codec_ctx->width / 2;
source.linesize[2] = video_codec_ctx->width / 2;

// only for bitrate regulation. irrelevant for sync.
source.
pts = pts;
pts++;

int out_length = frame_size + (frame_size / 2);
unsigned char *out = (unsigned char *) av_malloc(out_length);
int compressed_length = avcodec_encode_video(video_codec_ctx, out, out_length, &source);

(*env)->
ReleaseByteArrayElements(env, yuv_image, yuv_data,
0);

// Write to file too
if (compressed_length > 0) {
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);
pkt.
pts = last_audio_pts;
if (video_codec_ctx->coded_frame && video_codec_ctx->coded_frame->key_frame) {
pkt.flags |= 0x0001;
}
pkt.
stream_index = video_stream->index;
pkt.
data = out;
pkt.
size = compressed_length;
if (
av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_context,
&pkt) != 0) {
LOGI("Error writing video frame");
}
} else {
LOGI("??? compressed_length <= 0");
}

last_audio_pts++;

av_free(out);
return
compressed_length;
}

JNIEXPORT jintJNICALL
Java_com_google_android_apps_watchme_Ffmpeg_encodeAudioFrame(JNIEnv
*env,
jobject thiz,
        jshortArray
audio_data,
jint length
) {
if (!enable_audio) {
return 0;
}

short *audio = (*env)->GetShortArrayElements(env, audio_data, 0);
//LOGI("java audio buffer size: %i", length);

AVCodecContext *audio_codec_ctx = audio_stream->codec;

unsigned char *out = av_malloc(128000);

AudioBuffer_Push(audio, length
);

int total_compressed = 0;
while (

AudioBuffer_Size()

>= audio_codec_ctx->frame_size) {
AVPacket pkt;
av_init_packet(&pkt);

int compressed_length = avcodec_encode_audio(audio_codec_ctx, out, 128000,
                                             AudioBuffer_Get());

total_compressed +=
compressed_length;
audio_samples_written += audio_codec_ctx->
frame_size;

int new_pts = (audio_samples_written * 1000) / audio_sample_rate;
if (compressed_length > 0) {
pkt.
size = compressed_length;
pkt.
pts = new_pts;
last_audio_pts = new_pts;
//LOGI("audio_samples_written: %i  comp_length: %i   pts: %i", (int)audio_samples_written, (int)compressed_length, (int)new_pts);
pkt.flags |= 0x0001;
pkt.
stream_index = audio_stream->index;
pkt.
data = out;
if (
av_interleaved_write_frame(fmt_context,
&pkt) != 0) {
LOGI("Error writing audio frame");
}
}
AudioBuffer_Pop(audio_codec_ctx
->frame_size);
}

(*env)->
ReleaseShortArrayElements(env, audio_data, audio,
0);

av_free(out);
return
total_compressed;
}
```

Comment: _"but still errors are coming"_ **What** errors?

Comment: i paste my all code above that all code is showing error's

Comment: Again, **what** errors? Just saying that you're getting some errors is not useful if you don't say exactly what those errors are (i.e. the full, exact error messages. And if they refer to some specific line in your code or makefiles, point out which those lines are).

Comment: Hi Michael     Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\RAM-RAMADEVI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd''

Comment: when i run my app i am getting this exception in my console,Did you use this  yt-watchme-master when ever ?

Comment: So does the file C:\Users\RAM-RAMADEVI\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\‌​ndk-build.cmd exist?

Comment: yes i installed NDK in my android studio,I am begginer can u please guide me how can i solve this issue?

Comment: yes it was existed,But why this problem is coming?